# What is the probability of a multivariate hypergeometric given partial information?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a shuffled, standard deck of 52-cards, 5 cards are randomly dealt facedown.

From those 5 cards, 2 facedown cards are revealed and they're 1 Heart (♥) and 1 Spade (♥), but they're then flipped back over and shuffled with the other 3 facedown cards to leave 5 facedown again.

If we flip 2 cards randomly from those 5 again, what are our chances of getting 1 Heart (♥) and 1 Spade (♥) again?

To summarize the game state:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Target Cards | ♥ ♠ |
| Facedown Cards Dealt | ♥ ♠ **? ? ?** |
| Remaining Hearts Unknown (Deck or ? Facedown) | 12 |
| Remaining Diamonds Unknown (Deck or ? Facedown) | 13 |
| Remaining Clubs Unknown (Deck or ? Facedown) | 13 |
| Remaining Spades Unknown (Deck or ? Facedown) | 12 |
| Total 'Unknown' Cards | **50** |

My current attempt has been to try and interpret this as a sort of 'nested' combinations problem where I use the multivariate hypergeometric distribution to first individually calculate all cases of K(♥,♠,X) picked for the unknown facedown cards, i.e. where among the 3 facedown cards there are K(0,0,3) Hearts, Spades, and Misses picked, (1,0,2), (0,1,2), etc.. Constants would be N(12, 12, 26) for N(♥,♠,X) populations and 3 selections.

For all the 1st Step cases of K(♥,♠,X), we now have a set of probabilities  we can use for weighting each simpler 2nd Step probability. In this 2nd Step, the card populations P(♥,♠,X) are now the variables with the constants being choosing 2 cards for result K(1,1,0).

| ♥ | ♠ | X | K(♥, ♠, X) | 1st Step | ♥ | ♠ | X | P(♥, ♠, X) | 2nd Step | Final Weighted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | (0,0,3) | 13.30% | 1 | 1 | 3 | (1,1,3) | 10% | 1.33% |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | (0,1,2) | 19.90% | 1 | 2 | 2 | (1,2,2) | 20% | 3.98% |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | (0,2,1) | 8.80% | 1 | 3 | 1 | (1,3,1) | 30% | 2.64% |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | (0,3,0) | 1.10% | 1 | 4 | 0 | (1,4,0) | 40% | 0.44% |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | (1,0,2) | 19.90% | 2 | 1 | 2 | (2,1,2) | 20% | 3.98% |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | (1,1,1) | 19.10% | 2 | 2 | 1 | (2,2,1) | 40% | 7.64% |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | (1,2,0) | 4.00% | 2 | 3 | 0 | (2,3,0) | 60% | 2.40% |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | (2,0,1) | 8.80% | 3 | 1 | 1 | (3,1,1) | 30% | 2.64% |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | (2,1,0) | 4.00% | 3 | 2 | 0 | (3,2,0) | 60% | 2.40% |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | (3,0,0) | 1.10% | 4 | 1 | 0 | (4,1,0) | 40% | 0.44% |

Altogether, my answer here appears to be 27.89% overall for getting (♥,♠) again from picking 2 of the 5 facedown cards when we know there's already 1 ♥ and 1 ♠ among the 5. Without that partial information, we'd guess there would be a 12.7% chance of drawing (♥,♠) from needing to (13 pick 1) twice and (26 misses pick 0), divided by (52 cards pick 2).

$$  \frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{0}}{\binom{52}{2}} = 12.7\% $$

I'd like to say the value of that partial information was a nice 15.19% now, but I'm frankly very rusty on my math and:

(1) Not entirely sure this 'roundabout' way of doing my calculations has actually resulted in the correct answer.

(2) If there's a concept, distribution, or some other idea that already covers the scenario I've described here that could maybe even scale more easily to larger or more complex cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d go about it like this:

In $1$ of $\binom52=10$ cases you pick the same cards again, and then they’re hearts and spades with probability $1$.

In $\binom32=3$ cases you pick completely new cards, and then the probability to get hearts and spades is $\frac{12\cdot12}{\binom{50}2}$, since there are $12$ hearts and $12$ spades left.

In the remaining $6$ cases, you pick one old card and one new card, and the probability that the new card is the right suit is $\frac{12}{50}$.

Thus, your overall probability is

$$
\frac{1\cdot1+3\cdot\frac{12\cdot12}{\binom{50}2}+6\cdot\frac{12}{50}}{10}=\frac{3421}{12250}\approx27.93\%\;,
$$

which is close but not equal to your result. The discrepancy seems to be due to small errors in your numbers, for which I don’t see an obvious explanation – e.g., the first number in your “first step” column should be

$$
\frac{\binom{26}3}{\binom{50}3}=\frac{13}{98}\approx13.27\%
$$

instead of the $13.30\%$ you have.